# The easiest way to print two numpy arrays as a table

Tags: python, numpy

I have

```
x = np.array([1, 4, 5, ...100 more values])

y = np.array([1.23452324, 6.2341238, 11.1348219, ...100 more values])
```

I need to output it as a table:

```
1   1.235
4   6.234
5  11.135
```

I need to print arrays vertically, justified to the right side and values should be rounded to 3 decimals. Is there any elegant way?

PS. I've tried this:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(repr(x.item(i)).rjust((7)), repr(y.item(i)).rjust(7), end=' ')
    print(repr(z.item(i)).rjust(7))
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to implement any way from your research? What went wrong?

Comment: Do post the non-elegant ways you tried!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 4, 5])
>>> y = numpy.array([1.23452324,6.2341238, 11.1348219])
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})
>>> print(df)
   x          y
0  1   1.234523
1  4   6.234124
2  5  11.134822
```

Look up the Pandas documentation on how to format the numbers as you wish. In specific look for [`pandas.DataFrame.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html):

```
>>> df.round(3)
   x       y
0  1   1.235
1  4   6.234
2  5  11.135
```

Make sure you installed Pandas on your machine:

Python2/Python3:

```
pip3 install --user pandas
pip install --user pandas
```

Comment: Wow! That's really what I was talking about. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer to include the rounding.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>import numpy as np 

>>>x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>>y = np.array([12.3424, 323.1234, 125.4342, 342.1234, 654.4342, 234.3434])

>>>for x, y in zip(x, y):
       print('{0}\t{1:.1f}'.format(x, y))

    1     12.3
    2     323.1
    3     125.4
    4     342.1
    5     654.4
    6     234.3
```

Comment: Almost what I want! If only you could tell me how to round these values I would be really thankful

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov updated with rounding

Comment: Now there's a little bit strange output justification. I think pandas is a perfect fit in my case. Thank you anyway!

Comment: to play with the comma alignment and other formatting options... try....  for xy in list(zip(x, y)):
   print('{0:>3.0f}  {1:>6.1f}'.format(*xy))

Answer (score 2):

Before you begin, install `tabulate` package

from terminal:

```
conda install tabulate
```

then the rest will be:

```
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate


x = np.array([1, 4, 5, 100])
y = np.array([1.23452324, 6.2341238, 11.1348219, 100])

col_headers = ["x", "y"]

merged_array = np.array([x, y]).T


table = tabulate(merged_array , col_headers, tablefmt="fancy_grid", floatfmt = ".2f")

print(table)
╒════════╤════════╕
│      x │      y │
╞════════╪════════╡
│   1.00 │   1.23 │
├────────┼────────┤
│   4.00 │   6.23 │
├────────┼────────┤
│   5.00 │  11.13 │
├────────┼────────┤
│ 100.00 │ 100.00 │
╘════════╧════════╛
```

Comment: Also works fine. Thank you for answering my question!